# How to get geolocation with Vanilla JavaScript/Ajax - Country and City

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, geolocation

I'm learning JavaScript and Ajax. I don't want to use any libraries or frameworks.

I have found a code that uses this: https://codepen.io/Aurelian/pen/VyqemX

And my question is, how can make that with pure JavaScript? With no jQuery?

I need to re-do AJAX basics as I haven't done it in a long time.

Also, do I need to connect to the API? The URL part? How do other websites get the current location?

There are similar questions to this but they are all jQuery. So there is Vanilla JavaScript, please.

The JS code:

```
  jQuery.ajax( {
  url: '//freegeoip.net/json/',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(location) {
    // example where I update content on the page.
    jQuery('#city').html(location.city);
    jQuery('#region-code').html(location.region_code);
    jQuery('#region-name').html(location.region_name);
    jQuery('#areacode').html(location.areacode);
    jQuery('#ip').html(location.ip);
    jQuery('#zipcode').html(location.zipcode);
    jQuery('#longitude').html(location.longitude);
    jQuery('#latitude').html(location.latitude);
    jQuery('#country-name').html(location.country_name);
    jQuery('#country-code').html(location.country_code);
  }
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

> do I need to connect to the API? The URL part?

Yes. Well, kind of. The API figures out your location by examining the IP the request was made from. It's likely looking that IP in a database or something to lookup its location.

So if you wanna do the same thing, then yes, You do need to connect to the API. This process requires a lot more than just vanilla javascript and a browser and can't be done client side only.

Or can it?.. With that being said, it's possible to use the `geolocation` API available in most browser to detect the user location directly from the browser upon their permission. This gives a location coordinates (latitude, longitude) which you can then looking using Google Maps API or something like that.

**Read More:**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start#reverse

> I need to re-do AJAX basics as I haven't done it in a long time.

Not necessarily! Most Browsers nowadays supports the `fetch` API which makes a lot easier to do AJAX requests and such .

https://caniuse.com/#feat=fetch

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Good luck!

Comment: How do I convert the latitude and longitude? I believe those numbers are stored in a database which google and other companies have, so they can determine the location. So in other words, we need to get the API right?

The google tutorials are strange xd I'm confused by this xd